# Linq where on include

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm stuck with this linq query.

I've this tables.

```
ID  A   B   C  D
1   some data 
2   some other data
```

Then, For every record on that table I may have none or many rows

```
ID  TableA_ID R
1   1         1
2   1         2
3   1         5
4   2         2
```

For example. Row 1 (some data) has 3 rows on table B.

I tried using

```
tableA.Include(x => x.tablebchilds.Where( d => d.R == 1)).ToList()
```

but it is not working. With many others varation.

The objective of this query is to return `tableA.row` #1 if I pass it `1` as value (value of `R`). `Number <> 2` won't give any result.

Tables are linked on EF. So `TableB.tableA_ID` is Foreign key of `tableA.ID`

**Edit #1**

I tried the answers in the question marked as duplicated with no luck. Give that 2 tableA.rows if the user insert **1** as parameter, linq query should return **Row #1, some data**. If **2** is passed as parameter, nothing is return.

A working SQL statement is:

```
SELECT [TableA].* FROM [TableA] JOIN [TableB] ON [TableA].[Id] = [TableB].[TableA_Id] WHERE [TableB].[R] = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Gert Arnold: I don't think it's a duplicate, because I think Engerlost is asking something else, though admittedly, it's not very clear.

Comment: @jjj Maybe. The point is that `Include` with `Where` isn't possible (sadly enough). This is being asked over and over again. There is a work-around which I describe in the duplicate. If the OP tries to achieve something else, yes it should be clarified.

Comment: @GertArnold The query on that answer won't work in my case. I know that  Include with where is not possible. I'll edit my question to clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I still can't quite follow what you're after. It looks like an `Any` query. Probably it helps to show working code and/or sample data (input and output). Also show where you've got navigation properties (like A.B). These invariably make life a lot easier. I'll reopen anyway, because it doesn't seem to be a duplicate, but it's liable to go down as "unclear what you're asking".

Comment: @GertArnold thanks Gert. I leave some data on Marc's answer. To sum it up: The SQL statement works OK. I'm trying to do that in linq ef. Much appreciated

Comment: @GertArnold It's not so much that is doesn't work, its that BY DESIGN YOU SHOULD NOT BE ABLE TO DO IT. Because it's just damned confusing, the property no longer maps to what it says it maps to.

Comment: @Aron I'm not sure what doesn't work because I don't know what the OP wants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have database relationship properly configured this have to work.

```
tableA.Include(x => x.tableBChilds).Where(tableA => tableA.tableBChilds.Any(b => b.R== 1)).ToList();
```

Comment: It doesn't work or I'm missing something. I edited my question with a working SQL statement.

Comment: What happens? Exception message?

Comment: When you say ´tableA.ID == 1´ **1** should be the **R** value not tableA.ID. I need whatever  ´tableA´ rows have 1 in  ´ tableB´. Thanks!

Comment: Don't you say that R value is the foreing key of TableA.ID in your answer? If this it's true filtering `tableA.ID == 1 ` you are selecting tableA row with TableBChild.R == 1

Comment: Sorry. I made a typo there. TableB has a FK to TableA and the R value. If **1** is the param it should return tableA.row#1. In case of **2**, both rows are returned. (I edited the original question with the new data) Thanks

Comment: When I write tableA.tableBChilds.R (R is not in the intellisense) and it throws an error. I can't access any tableB properties this way.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that TableChilds was a collection, answer updated